# Does the android digital-signature change?

Tags: android, security, apk, digital-signature

Does the apk **digital-signature** **changes** when the developer release a new **update** for the app?

Answer (score 1):

The digital signature changes, as it does whenever you are signing different content.

However:

- the signing key does not change
- [the `signatures` field of a `PackageInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures) will not change, because that is really the public key of the signing key, not the digital signature value (despite the field's name)

Comment: so does that mean the only method to identify the authenticity of the app is the public key?

Comment: @LiveSeven: I do not know what you mean by "identify the authenticity of the app". Checking the public key indicates whether the app was signed by the key that you expected (e.g., from the original developer) or not.

Comment: just for updates I mean, to verify that the update is coming from a genuine source or the apk is from the original developer.

Comment: @LiveSeven: Then yes, checking to see if the signing key matches a known good value is the only method that I know of.